# Dynamic Multidimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Actually I want to create a three dimensional array dynamically in laravel , like

```
$product_des = array(
    1 => array(
        4 => array('a', 'b'),
        5 => array('c', 'd')
    ),
    2 => array(
        6 => array('d', 'e')
    )
);
```

But how to create it dynamically and access it on laravel view.

Comment: What you have tried so far, post your attempts

Comment: post your code in question

Comment: What do you want to do with this array?

Comment: can be done very easily, question is : what is the source of your multidimensional array? and how do you translate *that* source data to multi dimensional array?